# Detecting Angle using Kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a flat pan and using kinetic v1.

I want to receive the angle of the pan using kinetic camera. 
for eg: If I put the angle in 45 degrees so kinetic will read the closet or exact angle it placed.

is this possible or any solutions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how the data comes back in Kinect V1 but I believe this methodology should work for you.

First: You have to assume that the Kinect is your level of reference, if it is necessary to get the pans angle relative to the ground then make sure the Kinect is level with the ground.

Second: Separate the pan data from all other data. This should be straight forward, the pan should be the closets object so transmit the closest measurements into 3D coordinate points (array of x,y,z).

Third: Assuming you wish for horizontal angle find the highest and lowest grounds of data and average their depth from the camera. Then save both those depths and the vertical distance they are away from each other.

Fourth: Now you can essentially do the math for a triangle. Given you know the width of the pan(saves steps to know the objects size otherwise you have to estimate that too) you can solve for a triangle with sides a: distance to point 1, side b: distance to point 2, side c: size of pan and finding the angle of where points a and c or b and c meet will give you the horizontal angle of the pan relative to the Kinect.

Fifth: For verification your measurements came back correct you can then use the angle you found to calculate the width of the pan given the angle and distance of the top and bottom most points.

Needless to say, you need to make sure that your understanding of trig is solid for this task.